# Find the x-coordinates of two other points of inflection of $f(x)= \int \frac{x+1}{x^2+1}$, given there is an inflection point at $(1,1) $

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

$$f(x)= \int {\frac{x+1}{x^2+1}}$$

I have to find the x-coordinates of two other points of inflection, given there is an inflection point at (1,1).

My approach is to differentiate the equation, and then make that y=0, and use the null factor law rule to get $x=-x-\sqrt{2}$, $-x+1\sqrt{2}$.

My question: I am really unsure whether this is the right answer, this question is actually part of a larger question, in which the previous question asked me to find the x-coordinates of the points where the gradient of the graph of f is zero.

Would my answer of $x=-x-\sqrt{2}$, $-x+1 \sqrt{2}$ be the same as well? Or something else?

Comment: what's that mean here  ?"f= \int {x+1\x^2+1} " . do you want to type integral ?

Comment: You might find this helpful for formatting http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you heaps! My first attempt at formatting gone wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+1)+\arctan(x)\;$ does not have an inflection point at $(x,y)=(1,1),$ but the integrand 
$$h(x)= \frac{x+1}{x^2+1}$$
does have it. Computing $h''(x)\,$ and and solving $h''(x)=0\;$ gives a cubic equation after multiplying with $(x^2+1)^3$

$$0 = 2x^3+6x^2 -6x -2 = 2(x-1)(x^2+4x+1)$$

with the solutions $x=1,\,-2\pm \sqrt{3}$

Comment: Oh okay. That's why I was confused. I am meant to find the second derivative of the function, to get my x coordinates for the other inflexions.